# Не могу понять как переменная получает доступ к массиву

Tags: javascript, массивы, for, переменные

Есть такой код (просто пример). Не понимаю как переменная *i* получает доступ к элементам массива.

```
const myArray = ['first', 'second', 'third'];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}

/* Вывод
'first'
'second'
'third'
*/
```

Comment: Что значит `переменная i получает доступ к элементам массива`?

Comment: Ну т.е чтобы вывести элемент массива нужно использовать квадратные скобки и индекс. А тут вместо индекса, находится переменная i.

Comment: Вы хорошо понимаете как работают переменные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `i` принимает значение от 0 до 2
2. К элементу массива можно обратиться по индексу, например `myArray[0]`/`myArray[1]`/`myArray[2]`
3. Собственно, вместо хардкорного указания индекса ручками в виде 0, 1, 2 - в это место подставляется значение из переменной `i` (п.1) и получается ровно то же самое, что в п.2